# How to avoid repetitive code in HTML?

Tags: html

Suppose i have a class as follows which shows the available items i want to sell on my website. How should i avoid writing the same code again and again when i add new products to my site. Everytime i add a new product, only its image and the page where it points to will change. Is there any way to manage this efficiently ? Thanks in advance

```
<div class="sale">
        <div class="img-container"><a href="#"><img src="1.png">Product1</a></div>
        <div class="img-container"><a href="#"><img src="2.png">Product2</a></div>
        <div class="img-container"><a href="#"><img src="3.png">Product3</a></div>
        <div class="img-container"><a href="#"><img src="4.png">Product4</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The way to manage this efficiently would be to use a programming language instead of just html

Comment: Could you please explain which language are you referring to?

Comment: He's referring to only using html. This is how I understand it

Comment: You may go for client/server scripts to generate DHTML. Its upto you what do you prefer.

Comment: You could use Copy + Paste (CTRL + C, CTRL + V).

Comment: @Andrew Copy and Pasting code is probably the last thing you want to do. Anyways it looks like you are going to need a server to handle the products information (unless it's local to you). Then use PHP to generate that HTML from the server. That being said the question is too broad for an exact answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot many options to achieve DHTML.
A basic example using JavaScript:

```js
var details = [{
  'img': "http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/light-bulb-6.svg",
  'lbl': "Product 1"
}, {
  'img': "http://images.clipartpanda.com/light-bulb-vector-png-9czEXKbbi.svg",
  'lbl': "Product 2"
}, {
  'img': "http://images.clipartpanda.com/light-bulb-vector-png-light-bulb-7.svg",
  'lbl': "Product 3"
}];

var html = "";
for (var i = 0, l = details.length; l > i; i++) {
  html += "<div class=\"img-container\">";
  html += "<a href=\"#\">";
  html += "<img src=\"" + details[i].img + "\">" + details[i].lbl + "</a>";
  html += "</div>";
}

document.getElementsByClassName('sale')[0].innerHTML = html;
```

```css
.sale {
  border: 1px ridge grey;
}
.img-container {
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  margin: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}
.img-container img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sale">
  <div class="img-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="1.png">Product1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="2.png">Product2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="3.png">Product3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="4.png">Product4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

basically first you have to learn any server side technologies (e.g., Asp, NodeJS. PHP etc.) and database (e.g., mysql, MS Sql server) then, I am sure you will get your answer. More importantly  also learn **Javascript** or its one of library Jquery or preferably **AngularJS**.
For creating dynamic html you have to command on Javascript **at least**

Answer (score 0):

Almost in Every Back-end Technologies like as Node.js , Django there is a concept called
template . If you know or learn template then you can avoid repetition of your html code.And you can re-use your html code in another html files.

for Node.js [template](https://ejs.co/)

for Django [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/)